# Sending 250ms UDP price ticks over socket connection from C++ to nodejs processes crashing, why?

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, udp, ticker

Attempting to send UDP price ticks from a C++ "talker" process to a nodejs "listener" process, and I'm getting a crash.

Tick talking and listening is working for C++ to C++ processes. When I added the Nodejs piece listener, it blew up.

Any insight? Thx, Keith :^)

**Tick Data** Looks good:

```
Price unicasted: 49.58
Price unicasted: 50.00
Price unicasted: 50.24
Price unicasted: 50.09
Price unicasted: 49.81
```

**C++ Talker**

```
#define SERVERPORT "4950"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
    int rv;
    size_t numbytes;
    char* address = "192.168.1.100";

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(address, SERVERPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }
    sockfd = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);

    char myPrice[7];
    float f;
    while(1) {
        f = randPrice();
        ftoa(f, myPrice, 2); // Convert price to string
        myPrice[5] = '\n'; myPrice[6] = '\0';

        std::cout << "Price unicasted: " << myPrice;
        if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd, myPrice, strlen(myPrice), 0, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
            perror("talker: sendto");
            exit(1);
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**Node.js Listener**

```
var PORT = 4950;
var HOST = '192.168.1.100';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

while(1) {
    server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
        console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
    });
}

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

**Error** Eek!

```
pickledEgg> node udp.listener.js 
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#    
==== C stack trace ===============================    
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#
==== C stack trace ===============================
<--- Last few GCs --->

[14801:0x102806800]    13404 ms: Mark-sweep 1385.7 (1425.8) -> 1385.7 (1441.3) MB, 1099.6 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[14801:0x102806800]    14533 ms: Mark-sweep 1400.7 (1441.3) -> 1400.7 (1441.8) MB, 1099.3 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[14801:0x102806800]    15852 ms: Mark-sweep 1401.5 (1441.8) -> 1401.5 (1456.3) MB, 1317.5 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: semi-space copy, fallback in old gen Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::AllocateTargetObject(v8::internal::HeapObject*, v8::internal::HeapObject**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::Page*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::PageParallelJob<v8::internal::EvacuationJobTraits>::Task::RunInternal() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceAndCandidates() [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [/usr/local/bin/node]
11:     0   node                                0x0000000100bf1593 v8::base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace() + 19
    1   node                                0x0000000100bee739 V8_Fatal + 233
    2   node                                0x0000000100143e48 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) + 744
    3   node                                0x00000001005e03bb v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::AllocateTargetObject(v8::internal::HeapObject*, v8::internal::HeapObject**) + 1019
    4   node                                0x00000001005df6be v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject*) + 318
    5   node                                0x00000001005eb8eb v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::Page*) + 235
    6   node                                0x00000001005eb786 v8::internal::PageParallelJob<v8::internal::EvacuationJobTraits>::Task::RunInternal() + 198
    7   node                                0x0000000100b067d9 v8::platform::WorkerThread::Run() + 25
    8   node                                0x0000000100bf3187 v8::base::ThreadEntry(void*) + 87
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9250bc13 _pthread_body + 131
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9250bb90 _pthread_body + 0
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff92509375 thread_start + 13
Illegal instruction: 4
```

**EDIT 1: Subsequent Error**

```
node udp.listener.js 
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: bind EADDRINUSE 192.168.1.100:4950
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at _handle.lookup (dgram.js:242:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:105:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to insert `message` event handlers in endless loop `while(1)` so you get out of memory error. Most likely you only need to set handler only once.

Comment: Aargh! Good eye... obviously I'm trying to keep the listener up and running to receive all ticks.

Comment: After fixing this I got a new error, which I added as an EDIT 1 in the bottom, which looks like reasonably straight-forward double-bind error.

Comment: @kmiklas `EADDRINUSE` most likely implies that some application (maybe still running instance of this application?) is already using specified address/port pair.

Comment: yeah I had a stray C++ test process running that was already using the pair. It's working! :D :D :D